# Bypass MFA for Multi-Tenant Azure App using Graph API to access Partner Tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

We are an MSP who manages our customers Office 365 tenancies.

We have a portal that we log into using the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL.js) and receive a token authenticating against the app successfully.

As we have an established 'Relationship' with these other customers tenancies, we can manage them with global admin permissions using our own credentials (delegated permissions).
The structure is something like so:

1. Our Tenancy

   1. Customer 1
   2. Customer 2

Once logged into our portal, we have an array of tenant ID's for Customer 1 and Customer 2.
We use the same MSAL.js to connect to their tenancy specifying the App ID and the authority of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}`

Authentication is successful and we can use the Graph API to collect data ie, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization`

We can run this an unlimited amount of times whilst logged into our portal and it will recursively run through each tenant and successfully retrieve data.

As soon as we log out of the portal and back in, we are given the following error:

> AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator,
>   or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor
>   authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.

Multi factor pops up on my phone for each customer, once this is authorised once again I can use the API constantly, however next log out/in, the same issue happens.

I have specified Named Locations with the IP of multiple sites, I have also excluded these particular IP's for MFA which works when simply signing into https://portal.office.com, we do not receive an MFA request.

Office 365 techs review this with me, but were unable to get this working and directed me to Azure support which requires a further subscription.

Is anyone aware of a method we can use to bypass MFA when connecting to the tenants using the API?

EDIT:

Our method for obtaining a token is outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-cloudsolutionprovider

Comment: You are Microsoft CSP? If so, the reason may be that the method you were using to get an access token is not compatible with an account that has MFA enabled. You will need to implement the secure application model framework to obtain an access token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/enable-secure-app-model. See this post: https://www.microsoftpartnercommunity.com/t5/Multi-Factor-Authentication-MFA/Cannot-access-some-graph-endpoints-with-MFA-enabled-accounts/m-p/12126#M409.

Comment: Hi Allen, Thanks for your links. Yes we are a CSP! I've attempted to implement this via PowerShell however after running the cmdlet to create the `New-PartnerAccessToken` I am redirected and requested to sign in, which I do. I am the presented with a 'Need pre-consent' page with the comment "Placeholder text that is of similar expected length as what we will likely receive from the PMs. Fill this in once the new string is available for use."

I can confirm I've logged into the App page and consented to all permissions here.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Hi Allen, looking further into this, we want to use the Graph API, not the partner center API. The method we use works, just asks for MFA for each customer every log off/on.

Comment: The solution we are using is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-cloudsolutionprovider

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just returned from vacation. It seems that this issue has been resolved. You can post an answer and mark it as answered to help other people.

Comment: Issue is not resolved Allen, I have a ticket with Azure AD support, I will share my findings once they have resolved